# I am querying webtrends via odbc the data values are truncated at 255 chars, is this a limitation of the WT ODBC driver?

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, odbc, webtrends

The version of Webtrends is 8.7 so i cannot use the .net sdk or the new RESTful. So I am limited to using ODBC.

I have the latest WT ODBC driver 8.07.05.01 and I am using .NET 4.

Code below

```
    Dim objConnection As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    Dim objCommand As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim objReader As System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    Dim sTimePeriod As String = "2013.m09.d03"

    objConnection = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection("DSN=WT_DATA")

    objConnection.Open()

    Dim strSQl As String

    strSQl = String.Format("SELECT QueryStringGif.QueryString " & _
                 "FROM QueryStringGif  " & _
                 "WHERE (QueryStringGif.TimePeriod='{0}')",sTimePeriod)

    objCommand = New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(strSQl, objConnection)
    objReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()

    While (objReader.Read())

         Dim url As String = objReader(0).ToString
         myLogSession = waProcessor.GetLogSession(url)
         If Not myLogSession Is Nothing Then
                '# add to batch
                myBatch.LogSessions.Add(myLogSession)
         End If
    End While
```

Which instead of pulling the whole QueryString only pulls the first 255 characters.  I know that there is more data there, because if I do the following query:

SELECT QueryStringGif.QueryString, len(QueryStringGif.QueryString)
FROM QueryStringGif
WHERE (QueryStringGif.TimePeriod='2013.m09.d03')

The length of the field is always greater than 255.

So is this a config Issue or a limitation on WebTrends.